# Cannot access DevExpress ASPxDateEdit in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

My sample code is

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert(deEnd.GetDate());
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>    
        <dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="deEnd" ClientInstanceName="deEnd" 
           runat="server">
        </dx:ASPxDateEdit>    
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But I get error as `"Uncaught ReferenceError: deEnd is not defined"` even though I have specified ClientInstanceName.
Even If I try to use  `var d = $("#<%=deEnd%>").GetDate();`
I get error as `'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).GetDate is not a function'`.

Comment: I think you can use client-side event here, are you want to get dateedit value after date changed or something else?

Comment: I need to pass the date value from button click to soap request through.

Comment: If you want to send request after the date is changed, just handle `DateChanged` event of the dateedit control in client-side. Still don't know why it returns `undefined` state besides it defined in `ClientInstanceName`.

Comment: could you try with moving the script tag after the form tag in your body.

Comment: i need to pass date value from 'setInterval' timer to soap so somehow need to make this work.

Comment: 'moving the script tag after the form tag' worked. Many thanks

Comment: Welcome.. What happening was your javascript code was executing before DOM had rendered completely. Always put your javascript files/code at the end of your page.